# Is logistic regression the way to go?

Tags: logistic, binary-data

My data has two dichotomous variables: culture (A and B), emotion (X, Y). Participants in two  countries (A and B) rated 16 sound-clips on these two variables.

RQ1: Are people able to distinguish the emotion clips across culture?

RQ2: Are people able to distinguish the cultural background of the speaker in the clip?

Is a logistic regression the appropriate way to tackle this? Are there any smarter options?

Comment: Depends on the scale of the rating variable.

If your theory allows you to consider the rating variable as continuous data, you can go for ANOVA and Facorial ANOVA.
If your rating variables is ordinal, you can stick with logistic regression. 

A sample data would help me to give you more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mathematically define what it means for people to distinguish the emotion and cultural background of the clips. Does it mean people perform better than 50%? Does it mean they perform better than the proportion they would be expected to get right if they were guessing knowing only the marginal proportion of each category (which may not be 50%)? Once you've chosen a definition, you can move forward and test the hypothesis with a model and appropriate statistical tests.

Let's say to distinguish is to get the answer correct 50% or more of the time. You want to test if, for each combination of participant country, speaker cultural background, and clip emotion, the proportion of correct answers is different from .5. None of your research questions seem to concern the effect of these variables on the ability to distinguish, just whether participants in each group can distinguish. You can fit a specially parameterized logistic regression model to your data to be able to answer this question for each of the 8 combinations of predictors you observe.

To have a probability of getting the correct answer to be .5 is to have the odds be 1 and the log odds to be zero. So, you can test whether the log odds of getting the correct answer is different from zero. You can create a variable that represents the 8 conditions (i.e., the interactions between participant country, speaker cultural background, and clip emotion) and a variable that represents whether the emotion of the clip was correctly guessed and another that represents whether the cultural background of the speaker was correctly guessed. You can fit a logistic regression for each outcome separately with the 8-level condition variables as the sole predictor and no intercept. For each outcome, the coefficient on each condition level is the log odds of getting the outcome correct. Each coefficient comes with a hypothesis test that tests whether the coefficient is different from zero. If it is, and if in particular the coefficient is greater than zero, then you have evidence that those with that condition are getting the answer correct better than 50%.

In R, the model would look like this:

```
fit <- glm(emotion_correct ~ 0 + interaction(culture, emotion, speaker_country),
           data = data, family = binomial)
summary(fit)
```

You can do this separately with each outcome (i.e., `emotion_correct` and `speaker_correct`) to answer your two research questions for the 8 combinations of conditions. This doesn't immediately allow you to answer the question of what factors affect the ability of participants to get the answers correct. To do that with this model, you can perform contrast tests (e.g., using the `glht` function in the `multcomp` package), which allow you to test whether combinations of levels have different from responses from each other.